# execute script automatically at 2:00 a.m?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want this procedure to be executed everyday 2:00 a.m. Also, i want to pass date parameter to the procedure. Suppose today is 28th july, 2010, then i want to pass 27th july, 2:00 am to the procedure. This way i want that all records inserted after 27th july, 2:00 am should be backed up in some other table. This is my procedure.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Alter PROCEDURE spBackupRows
(
    @Date datetime
)
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @ItemId int, @ItemName varchar(100), @Description varchar(50), @ItemCreatedDateTime datetime

    Declare myCursor Cursor FOR
        Select * from tblItems Where ItemCreatedDateTime > @Date

    Open myCursor

    Fetch Next From myCursor INTO @ItemId,@ItemName,@Description,@ItemCreatedDateTime

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin

        INSERT INTO tblBackUpData
        (ItemId,ItemName,Description,ItemCreatedDateTime)
        Values (@ItemId,@ItemName,@Description,@ItemCreatedDateTime)

        Fetch Next From myCursor INTO @ItemId,@ItemName,@Description,@ItemCreatedDateTime

    End

    Close myCursor
    Deallocate myCursor

END
GO
```

The problem i face is how do i make this procedure fire automatically? and also pass `datetime` parameter to the procedure?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: #1, there is no '2:00am midnight' on my clock.  #2, this belongs on superuse.com

Comment: Why do you want to pass in a datetime when you can use the DateAdd and GetTime/GetUTCTime functions in your SP?

Comment: Hi spender, it's fine even if i don't pass datetime in procedure. But important thing is how do i make it fire automatically?

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you on? SQL Agent should be the choice unless you are on Express.

Comment: No that's version. Not edition! If you are on Enterprise/Standard/Workgroup or basically anything other than Express SQL Agent is available.

Comment: I am using Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[How to: Schedule a Job (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx)

> 1. In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server Database Engine, and then expand that instance.
> 2. Expand SQL Server Agent, expand Jobs, right-click the job you want to schedule, and click Properties.
> 3. Select the Schedules page, and then click New.
> 4. In the Name box, type a name for the new schedule.
> 5. Clear the Enabled check box if you do not want the schedule to take effect immediately following its creation.
> 6. For Schedule Type, select one of the following:
>
>    - Click Start automatically when SQL Server Agent starts to start the job when the SQL Server Agent service is started.
>    - Click Start whenever the CPUs become idle to start the job when the CPUs reach an idle condition.
>    - Click Recurring if you want a schedule to run repeatedly. To set the recurring schedule, complete the Frequency, Daily Frequency, and Duration groups on the dialog.
>    - Click One time if you want the schedule to run only once. To set the One time schedule, complete the One-time occurrence group on the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server Agent to schedule a job every midnight then you can use the token (DATE)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175575.aspx

```
EXEC spBackupRows DATEADD(hour, -22,  $(ESCAPE_NONE(DATE)))
```

Assuming that you schedule the job @ midnight

Answer (score 1):

For this you should create a schedule and Job, the [how to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175138.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You can use SQL Server Agent to schedule a job every midnight then you can use the token (DATE)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175575.aspx